# Can I pass Surface between Activities?

Tags: android

I researched and people saying we cannot pass View between Activities because of different Context, but

I saw the Android source code of Surface actually implements Parcelable. Does that mean we can pass a Surface between Activities?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if the activities in same process. But why you need to manage surface by yourself? The surface to your activity has been set already by system, you can not set the surface again.